# Yii how to invoke an event handler on each request

Tags: web-services, rest, yii, yii-events

Is it possible in Yii to invoke an event handler so that it executes on each controller action call. 
Basically I have a RESTful application. On each request, currently, it explicitly calls an authentication function. What I want is the authentication function calls when any request is made.

What I did

```
class MyController extends RestController{
 public function actionDosomething(){
  $this->authenticate();// I don't want this line to be put in every controller action.
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is the **beforeAction** callback. Place this in your main Controller file.

```
public function beforeAction($action) {

     if(in_array($action, array( /* you list of actions */ ))) 
     {
       //do your thing
     }
}
```

Comment: Seems to be the exact answer. Thank you very much.

Comment: Please do mark this answer as complete if it satisfies your requirements, thanks :)

Comment: Yes, great. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 1):

Another option (in my opinion the more Yii-like approach) is to write a filter and then apply it as desired using the `filters` method.

It will give you even more flexibility in the future:
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.controller#filter